# Кнопка для выключения/включения музыки через AVaudioplayer

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Как сделать кнопку для выключения и включения музыки с помощью AVaudioplayer? на swift для ios в xcode
вот код который я использую

```
var audioplayer = AVAudioPlayer()

do {
        audioplayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL.init(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "extended2var", ofType: "mp3")!))
        audioplayer.prepareToPlay()
        audioplayer.numberOfLoops = -1;
    } catch {}
```

при нажатии на кнопку исполняется этот код и музыка начинает играть

```
@IBAction func start(_ sender: Any) {
    audioplayer.play()
}
```

но музыка не останвливается если использовать

```
@IBAction func stop(_ sender: Any) {
    audioplayer.pause()
}
```

и я не знаю как сделать это всё в одной кнопке

Comment: Напишите, как вы делаете. Здесь не принято задавать вопросы, не попробовав решить их самостоятельно.

Comment: Дополнил вопрос

Comment: То есть вы хотите, чтобы была одна кнопка, и она отвечала и за включение, и за выключение музыки?

Comment: да именно так мне и надо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделайте один метод и привяжите к кнопке:

```
@IBAction func togglePlay(_ sender: Any) {
  if audioplayer.isPlaying {
    audioplayer.pause()
  } else {
    audioplayer.play()
  }
}
```

Comment: спасибо за помощь но возникла другая проблема сама кнопка и привязка работает только на стартовом view controller то есть который самы первый ан а любом другом он не привязывается и не работает не подскажите что с этим делать?

Comment: Это уже другой вопрос, формулируйте его в отдельном вопросе. Если участник помог вам с оригинальным вопросом, принимайте ответ.